# Mistake in density computation

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

This is regarding [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4569433).

I had **incorrectly** answered it as:

> The integration can be thought of geometrically:
> The set of values that $X$ and $Y$ jointly take is the triangle cornered at $(0,0)$, $(0,1)$, and $(1,1)$. This has area $\frac{1}{2}$. For $Y\le y$, the relevant area is $\frac{y^2}{2}$.
> So, $Pr(Y\le y) = y^2$ for $0\le y\le 1$. Differentiation gives the density.

A [correct answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4569476/1016494) was given by user *RobPratt*.

I confirmed its correctness by running a simulation and plotting the histogram. [Code here](https://pastebin.com/PeXwrYMM).

I could not understand where my approach goes wrong.

Comment: This is false because the repartition on this triangle is not uniform.

Answer (score 1):

The joint PDF of $X$ and $Y$ is
$$
\frac{1_{[x,1]}(y)}{1-x}\,,\quad\quad\,x,y\in[0,1]\,.
$$
Therefore,
\begin{align}
\mathbb P\{X\le a,Y\le b\}&=\int_0^a\int_0^b\frac{1_{[x,1]}(y)}{1-x}\,dy\,dx=
\int_0^a\frac{b-x}{1-x}1_{\{x\le b\}}\,dx=\int_0^{\min(a,b)}\frac{b-1}{1-x}+1\,dx\\[2mm]
&=-(b-1)\int^{1-\min(a,b)}_1\frac{du}{u}+\min(a,b)\\
&=(1-b)\ln\Big(1-\min(a,b)\Big)+\min(a,b)\,.
\end{align}
In particular, the marginal CDF of $Y$ is (with $a=1$)
$$
\mathbb P\{Y\le b\}=(1-b)\ln(1-b)+b\,.
$$
This agrees with RobPratt's solution in the linked and closed question.

Comment: Thanks @KurtG. I get my mistake: shouldn't assume uniform joint density over the triangle. Could you also explain why the pdf differs significantly from the maximum of two $U[0,1]$ variables? This question seems similar to that one.

Comment: @abs The reason for that difference is that $Y$ is not the maximum of two $U[0,1]$ variables.